# Difference between Rx and [Rx]

Tags: assembly, arm, lpc

```
LDR R0, R1    ; statement 1
LDR R0, [R1]  ; statement 2
```

What is the difference between two statements?

In statement 1, is the address of register stored in R0?

In statement 2, is the 4 bytes of data pointed by R1 loaded into R0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `ldr r0, [r1]` loads 4 bytes from memory, using R1 as the address.

The 2nd operand of `ldr` has to be memory, using some addressing mode<sup>1</sup>, not a bare register.

`LDR R0, R1` is either a syntax error, or **tries to use R1 as a symbol name** (like any other string like `ldr r0, foo`), not a register.  If you'd bothered to try it, you'd see an error message like `Error: internal_relocation (type: OFFSET_IMM) not fixed up` (from GNU `as`).  This is the same error message you get for `ldr r0, foo`, when your source file doesn't contain that label.

(If you did have an `R1:` label somewhere in your source, this `ldr R0, R1` load would reference it.  Disassembling again, you'd get `ldr r0, [pc, #4]` if that label is after 2 more instructions.  Again, exactly the same as if you used `foo` instead of `R1` as the symbol name.  Using register names as symbols is a bad idea for human readability, but that's what happens if you actually do this with the GNU assembler (from GNU binutils).  [How does the LDR instruction load constants into registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44801649/how-does-the-ldr-instruction-load-constants-into-registers) shows an example)

**If you want to copy registers, use `mov r0, r1`, a different mnemonic (and machine-code opcode) from `ldr`.**

---

**Footnote 1:** Or there's a pseudo-instruction form of ldr, like `ldr r0, =0x1234` to put a constant into a register with the assembler's choice of instructions, or in some assemblers always a PC-relative load from a nearby "literal pool".  But that kind of `ldr` in the asm source either assembles to `ldr r0, [pc, #offset]` or to some instruction(s) that aren't `ldr` at all.  [What does an equals sign = on the right side of a LDR instruction in ARM mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840754/what-does-an-equals-sign-on-the-right-side-of-a-ldr-instruction-in-arm-mean)